# Does Quine's Predicate Functorese maintain the existence of relations?

Tags: logic, ontology, philosophy-of-logic

Quine's predicate functorese has been proposed as a "feature-placing" language for ontological nihilism (Strawson, Azzouni, Dasgupta, Diehl). This is often used to eliminate objects and individuals from ontology. Assuming that works, does predicate functorese still maintain the existence of primitive relations even without objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL; DR Not according to Quine, and not according to common alternatives. However, while existence of relations is ruled out by Quine, one can reconcile PFL (predicate functor logic) with both existence and non-existence of relations on alternative views.

### Quine's criterion and PFL

Quine's criterion, "to be is to be a value of a quantifiable variable", applies specifically to classical FOL. PFL, like any other language, has to be paraphrased into FOL before its ontological commitments can be judged. As he stressed in Algebraic Logic and Predicate Functors:

> "*When a theory is given the usual quantificational form, the things that the theory accepts as existing are indeed the things that it accepts as the values of its variables of quantification. If a theory is given another form, moreover, there is no sense in asking what the theory accepts as existing except as we are in a position to say how to translate the theory into the usual quantificational form.*"

So, by Quine's lights, PFL is useless to nihilists. Since it is paraphrasable into the usual FOL with object variables it can not absolve them of commitment to objects. A good discussion of Quine's own reconciliation of his criterion with PFL is [Collins's chapter Quine on Ontological Commitment in Light of Predicate-Functor Logic](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198864288.001.0001/oso-9780198864288-chapter-4).

### PFL without paraphrase

What if we keep the criterion but, *pace* Quine, reject the paraphrase part? That would still not entail commitment to relations. Unless one intends to quantify over predicates (relations), having named predicates in the language does not entail ontological commitment to them. So existence of relations does not follow.

However, it has to be said, such partial adoption of Quine's conception is a cheat. There is no quantification over *anything* in PFL, it is like propositional logic in this regard, but that is because an equivalent end is accomplished there *by other means* (the cropping function, a.k.a. the derelativization functor). We are starting to see the wisdom of Quine's paraphrase-first requirement. Without it one can escape, or impose, ontological commitments by mere technical trickery. But this raises the question of what makes classical FOL so special that it should be uniquely revealing as to theory's ontological commitments. According to Collins, Quine does not give a fully satisfactory answer to this question, nor is a principled one likely to emerge:

> "*As things stand,
> treating FOL as privileged depends upon dubious considerations. Indeed, if we adopt
> a generic criterion of ontological commitment in terms of predicate satisfiability,
> as Quine suggests, then there is not so much a symbolic criterion of ontological
> commitment, as simply a commitment to the idea of a universe of entities, whose
> role as truthmakers becomes perspicuous in FOL, but is strictly independent of FOL... Thus, we need not worry about nihilism or absolutism as being engendered by a choice of logical form,
> for serious ontological commitment is only dimly tracked, if at all, by a choice of
> logical form.*"

### Fictionalism and nihilism

Of course, one can reject Quine's procedure in its entirety, and many do, but then they have to come up with an alternative way of determining what does or does not contribute to ontology. Otherwise, the question of what our language commits us to take as existing is empty. One radical response is that it commits us to *nothing at all*, everything can be talked about "as if". This is the position of [fictionalists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism/). If a nihilist wishes to adopt this position then, strictly speaking, she has no need for PFL, already the presence of objects in FOL is merely the presence of useful fictions. But PFL does better in a Wittgensteinian sense: it does not just *say* that objects are superfluous in a fictionalist caption, it *shows* it.

This said, nothing forces object nihilists to go full fictionalism. Absent Quine's criterion, one is free to advance non-linguistic (metaphysical, scientific or pragmatic) arguments in favor of picking what does and does not exist, and it does not have to be determined by linguistic form. Proponents of relational ontologies typically do not reify *all* relations, only those "grounded" in science, for example. Here is Collins's surmise:

> "*The speaker of predicate-functorese effectively talks in predicates. Imagine, however, that she was introduced to the concept of a subject. This concept offers her a choice. On the one hand, she may posit a univocal subject — the Absolute — and let the predicates just be modifiers of it. It is unclear to me if such would capture what Spinoza and various idealists thought, but no matter: the Absolute would make true our truths. On the other hand, she could go nihilist by way of appending a pleonastic subject to her predicates. On this view, every sentence would have the form familiar from ‘It’s raining’: It is such that F, in general. The idea of rendering all of our claims into feature-placement claims, such as weather reports, often goes by the name of ontological nihilism, and can be endorsed independently of the virtues of predicate-functor logic. My present claim, following Burgess, is not that ontological nihilism should be accepted, but simply that it is a position a speaker of predicate-functorese may adopt.*"

Comment: “ Unless one intends to quantify over predicates (relations), having named predicates in the language does not entail ontological commitment to them. So existence of relations does not follow.”

Suppose a different criteria for existence -“mind independence- were used. Under this criteria and not Quines, does the existence of relations follow from PFL?

Comment: @GhostRocket For something to follow from PFL the criterion has to be linguistic, i.e. it has to confer existence based on syntax. Whether a name can be a value of a variable is such a criterion. Mind independence, on the other hand, is a matter of interpretation, not syntax. The syntax of PFL has nothing to say about mind independence, so such criterion cannot be applied to PFL at all. Users are free to interpret its predicate names as existing relations, or not, or interpret some as existing and others as not.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. “ On the one hand, she may posit a univocal subject — the Absolute — and let the predicates just be modifiers of it. It is unclear to me if such would capture what Spinoza and various idealists thought, but no matter: the Absolute would make true our truths.” What does that mean?

Comment: This is where I am getting conceptually stuck: “While its combinatory principles operate differently from those of familiar natural languages, this should not create any deep difficulty in learning it.“ Why are those combinatory rules not considered relations?

Comment: @GhostRocket It means that PFL can be interpreted as describing relations of a single object, Absolute, to itself. It is redundant then to indicate this object explicitly, and a language with predicate symbols only is natural. But asserting Absolute's existence allows to interpret all sentences as true in the usual FOL way. "Combinatory principles" refer not to relations but to what replaces variables and quantification in PFL (cropping function), the principles of composing and parsing its expressions. And there is no learning difficulty because they are translatable into the familiar ones.

Comment: So, it does away with relations between objects, but not mappings and operations to itself? I think I understand now. Isn't that almost category-theoretic?

Comment: @GhostRocket The origin of the word "functor" is not category theoretic, Quine took it from Carnap where it meant transformation of syntactic expressions. But there is a loose analogy. Category theory eliminates elements that maps of sets act on and characterizes maps (morphisms) by structural properties instead. In a similar way PFL eliminates variables and characterizes quantified predicates through combinatorial transformations.

Answer (score 5):

In order for predicate functorese logic (PFL) to have the same expressiveness and utility of first order language (FOL) without ontic commitment of any objects as quantified bound variables suitable for ontological nihilists, the existence of primitive relations between objects have to be maintained in compositional predicates (functors) and in fact it's one the main ideas for Quine to invent this logic due to his famous *ontological parsimony* position. An example to preserve primitive relations can be referenced [here](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/ergo/12405314.0005.037/--language-for-ontological-nihilism?rgn=main;view=fulltext):

> consider the sentence ‘Every integer has a successor.’ Using Z for ‘integer’ and S for ‘successor,’ we will regiment this in FOL as ¬∃x(Zx ∧ ¬∃ySyx). Applying the conversion procedure, we get νρκZνρS, which, by our pronunciation guide... so our first example would correspond to ... ‘It is not (integering and not just successoring).’

So here objects (integers and successors) are replaced by primitive relational predicates *integering* and *successoring*. Another example for a single object without relation is the sentence ‘There's a cat’, and the nihilist would say ‘It is catting’ with PFL interpreting existence of object as some more abstract feature predicate as a distinctive relation to some other feature like dogging. Finally besides the above primitive relations preserving syntax, a rich semantics interpretation provided from a metalanguage is also important to accomplish nihilist's goal.

> One difficult issue concerns how to give a nihilistically acceptable semantics for predicate functorese. Existing proposals for such a semantics will be unacceptable because they use a domain-theoretic—ultimately set-theoretic—model theory. To avoid this objection, a suitably enriched *feature-placing language* might provide a metalanguage for predicate functorese. But giving this is not the task for this paper... Finally, it would seem that PF has all the hallmarks of a speakable language: it has a clear compositional structure in accordance with a few simple rules. While its combinatory principles operate differently from those of familiar natural languages, this should not create any deep difficulty in learning it. Thus, the prospects for using PF as the nihilist’s fundamental language appear good.

Comment: That would mean Azzouni’s claim that such a language totally eliminates al relations is false, correcr?

Comment: @GhostRocket I'm not clear about the reference of above Azzouni's claim. Azzouni is a nominalist about abstract (math) object and argues that nothing would change if mathematical objects ceased to exist in a reference of Azzouni's student's paper here (https://philarchive.org/archive/MARNWS). He's a realist about physical objects while denying relations ontic commitment. Like math structualism trying to use category/functor theory as universal math foundation, PFL has similar spirit to treat predicate functorial relation as ontic instead of usual subject which turned to fictional "it" in PFL.

Comment: @GhostRocket having said above, of course for a nihilist there's no ontic commitment about anything by definition, any (formal) language/logic can only express like a poet's metaphors simply for the *convenience* of communication and nothing is really committed. So after getting rid of the existential and other quantifiers/variables, predicate functors just syntactically better fit nihilists, relations are expressed more "ontic like" than objects which simply treated as an abstract imaginary "it", you can even use imaginary number "i" if you like.

Comment: Whether Azzouni is truly a nominalist is a matter of debate (Otavio Bueno labled his position deflationary nominalism). But this much is clear: He denies the existence of both relations and individuals/objects, leaving only "feature". Azzouni's claim is the only thing left to describe the world is a feature-placing language using predicate functor logic.

Comment: Is the ontic nihilist position considered common in modern philosophy? Are there any good reasons for rejecting it?

Comment: @GhostRocket so for Azzouni "it's just integering" (integer object) is not interpreted as functorial *relation* within PA or ZFC but a *feature* placed, same goes for "successoring". It smells more like fictionalism. Feature and relation boundary is not clear-cut and both are described as property via function/map in math and predicate in logic (number 2 can be also thought of as a *doubling* function). Very few philosophers hold nihilism seriously (some claim it's not even a position and easily lead to pessimism, most don't like tragedy) and skepticism or nominalism are more welcomed...

Comment: If it’s “just integering” isn’t that functionally equivalent to relating to itself though? I understand that position is drawing terminologial distinctions bit are they actual distinctions?

Comment: @GhostRocket for a true nominalist or nihilist, integer 2 cannot be conceived as an additional copy of an object since there're no exact copies in our actual world. Many realists such as Kant conceive it as some synthetic a priori ontic existence like space and time, Occam would say it's just a mode of difference perceived in mind, 3 is another such a mode of difference. Say your thought about some thing changed (2ing), then changed again (3ing). So if you realize object (integer) is just modality, then clearly modality can be interpreted as relating to "it"self in differentiable modes...

Comment: I understand but if they wind up being functionally equivalent, wouldn’t that be a distinction without a substantive difference/congruence? It seems like the nihilist is trying to assert something out of existence by verbal fiat.

Comment: @GhostRocket nihilist essentially doesn't commit to anything (object or relation), while most nominalists at least assert something having ontic existence such as Hartry Field's Science without numbers, he still asserts physical objects/space/time as real. So PFL just syntactically fits nihilists, yes the predicate functor is a verbal fiat to place feature, property, or relation (ordered-pair in set theory or function/mapping).

Comment: That makes sense. I think I realize why few people accept nihilism: if one is using logical operations and claim one isn’t just by changing the name of what you’re doing, what has that effectively accomplished? Do you agree?

Comment: @GhostRocket yes I agree. Logic is not poetry, it cannot be seriously committed to nothing and say this logic is just dreaming. Ontic nihilism should be a quietism regarding language/logic ideally imho, some nihilists may just restrict such POV to epistemology like Buddhism's anatta or two-truths doctrine.

Comment: In addition to ontological nihilism, can one modify predicate functorese so that there is a single unique "object", which we might think of as "reality", and all the predicates describe it? If we want to use Quine's criterion for ontological commitment, this might be a way of translating something like Spinoza's metaphysics into logical form, where all the seemingly separate entities we have names for are actually "modes" of a single unique substance that Spinoza calls "God". Perhaps this could also be used to translate "structural realist" metaphysical views like that of Ladyman and Ross.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I think PFL for many cases already could do that by restricting to use a single generic "it" as the sole subject of a proposition like above example, with compositional functors to describe relations to other things. If the relation is 3-ary or more, you have to find a compositional way to *nihil* away those objects via nesting predicate functors to construct Spinoza logic. But it most likely won't have same expressiveness like FOL for some complicated cases which may not be able to do so or have to be simplified and approximated like using a poem to describe Maxwell eqn.

Comment: In terms of informal English, I was thinking that a sentence like "there is a cat in the corner of my room" could be paraphrased as something like "reality is cat-like where reality is corner-of-my-room-like", so "reality" is the only "thing" being referred to and everything else is done with adjective phrases along with "where" which relates one adjective phrases to another. I'd guess it'd be possible to come up with a formal language like this but I haven't looked into the details of predicate functorese so I don't know how similar it'd be, or whether it'd be less expressive than FOL.

Comment: @Hypnosifl an obvious case in your described Spinoza logic with only single universal subject which has trouble to have same expressiveness as FOL is dependent condition (relation), eg, to calculate Fibonacci sequence in primitive recursion. Since normally you need an ontic committed intermediary variable to pass to next recursion, but your PFL functor is predicated which only returns truth value, then how can you pass down? For your "It's (catting and (just cornering (some walling)))" example there's no need for any dependency to be passed between the 3 predicates as a simple description...

Comment: So that would be a case where predicate functorese is weaker than FOL? If we wanted to make the Spinozistic/structuralist logic stronger we could have existential and universal quantifiers which apply to predicates of a given form, like "for all locii of the structure S with x-variable-indexed predicates of the form Px(S), ..." which would apply to predicates with a constant term substituted for x, like P1(S) and P2(S) and P3(S) etc. Then one could have a type of predicate Nx(S) that says the structure S has a natural number x-like locus, & a successor predicate that relates diff values of x.

Comment: (cont) For example, succ(N1(S)) = N2(S), and we could write N2(S) = N1(S) + 1 as a shorthand for this. The successor predicate could also be two-valued so succ(Nx(S),Ny(S)) would mean taking the successor of Nx(S) y times. Then we could have a Fibonacci predicate that gave you the number of the xth term in the seq., for example since the third term in the sequence is 2 we would have F(N3(S)) = N2(S), likewise F(N4(S)) = N3(S), F(N5(S)) = N5(S) etc. Then we could say "for all locii of the structure S with x-variable-indexed predicates of the form Nx(S), F(Nx(S) + 2) = F(Nx(S) + 1) + F(Nx(S))"

Comment: @Hypnosifl remember for a strict Spinoza logic, ultimately you need to substitute all your "+ 1" into some other predicates such as integerlike incrementing and compose them functionally which will become immediately nearly human unreadable (actually through this language design simple drill one can realize to fully understand the world in a strict Spinozian way is to really spin one's head to annihilate almost everything). One can allow or modify PFL to have function predicate like FOL to return another feature (though not the realist's object in FOL) but still it'll be hard to read by human.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant when I said there could be a successor predicate and that *"succ(N1(S)) = N2(S), and we could write N2(S) = N1(S) + 1 as a shorthand for this. The successor predicate could also be two-valued so succ(Nx(S),Ny(S)) would mean taking the successor of Nx(S) y times"*. So with the two-valued version, Nx(S) + 2 would be shorthand for succ(Nx(S),N2(S)). This does get difficult to read, but then again it's also true that if one writes arithmetical propositions in FOL using the Peano notation it's hard to read, for example I think you'd have to write 3 as s(s(s(0))).

Comment: @Hypnosifl 2 difficulties in Spinoza logic with PFL treating any feature predicate as a specific mode of God. 1) Your impredicative higher-order logic recursion example "mode1(mode2(mode3))" has semantic issue to comprehend "what does it mean for a mode functorially composed by mode from the same source? Bear in mind that we only understand mode (weighted additive) superposition from physics". 2) Such PFL becomes fully modal logic since every feature functor is a mode which is not necessary thus is hard to derive its intensional truth value with PW semantics.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  from physics we all know all modes are intrinsically determined not conditioned on other modes. And all our simple cat examples are basically such unconditioned modes superpositions.

Comment: @Hypnosifl from categorical theory (CT) as math foundation POV, it's most easy to see Spinoza metaphysics may be the most difficult to achieve. According to CT the critical part is how to define an equivalence class relation upon another equivalence class relation so that one may have higher-order CT, but there's no theorem to prove there'll be a unique limit (due to Godel's incompleteness theorems for PA like powerful system I highly doubt there'll be any definite limit). But to achieve Spinoza's goal meaning you have to find a tower of "= relations" to identify all things into one thing...